# Computing the sum of values that came from a split String in an array in Java

Tags: java

Basically I am wondering how I could make a method that takes a String that has a series of decimal numbers separated by spaces and then (after splitting the string according to separate numbers) returns a double. Then using the doubles returned, returning the sum of all the decimal numbers rounded to the nearest whole number.

Example: Like let's say I input String “42.5 7.2 1.2” and I want to make it return the sum of all the decimal numbers rounded to the nearest whole number, which here would be 51.0.

Here is my attempt so far.

```
String s = text1; 
String[] ls;
ls = s.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i<= s.length(); i++){ 
    double a = Double.parseDouble(ls[i]);
```

Comment: Have you attempted to write the code to achieve this? If so, post your attempt here.

Comment: Yes i have here it part of the method I am referring to:String s = text1;
   String[] ls;
   ls = s.split(" ");
  
   for(int i = 0; i<= s.length(); i++){
    
    
   double a =  Double.parseDouble(ls[i]);

Comment: Sounds trivial. Which part of your homework is giving you problems?

Comment: So far you are pulling the double out, now you need a sum variable to store the sum in.

Comment: i wrote the part that i couldnt figure out above^^

Comment: yeah @Takendarkk I tried that and for some reason eclipse said there was an error

Comment: Post the code that gives you an error along with any error messages you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this (if I understand your question):

```
public static double roundedSum(String s) {
    String[] ls = s.split(" ");
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < ls.length; i++){ 
        sum += Double.parseDouble(ls[i]);
    }

    return Math.round(sum);
}
```

And then to test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "42.5 7.2 1.2";
    System.out.println ( roundedSum(s) ); // prints 51.0
}
```

---

As a note, your for loop was wrong:

```
for(int i = 0; i<= s.length(); i++){
```

First of all, you can never go until `<=` the length (unless you subtract 1). Indexes start at `0`, so the last position of the string is the length - 1.

Also, you were using the length of the string; you need to be using the length of the array as the bound.

Comment: ok i will try that man thanks and ill let ya know how it works

Comment: so i did the return part and i got an error saying void methods can't do return, so would i just do println?

Comment: @user3440080 `public static double roundedSum(String s) {` the method is not `void`. Change `void` to `double` in your code.

Comment: O ok and i did i'll try now

Comment: ok so i have this now else{
  if(n1 == 2){
   System.out.println("You chose \" compute rounded sum \" ");
   
   public static double roundedsum(String text1){
  
   String[] ls = text1.split(" ");
   double sum = 0;
   
  
   for(int i = 0; i< ls.length; i++){
   
   sum += Double.parseDouble(ls[i]);
   
     
    }
   return Math.round(sum);
   
   }

Comment: @user3440080 Go to http://pastie.org and post your code there, then send me the link to it. I'll take a look. I already know that the problem is that you have a method inside another method, though.

Comment: @user3440080 Ok this is that code fixed up: http://pastie.org/8952281 and I commented in the code where you went wrong. As a **strong** suggestion, please change your class name from `methodselection` to `MethodSelection`. In Java, coding conventions state that you must capitalize the first letter of every word in a class name. Also, change the method name `roundedsum` to `roundedSum` like I originally had. For methods and variables, capitalize the first letter of every word except for the first one. If this confuses you, ask your teacher about it or something. But there's the code.

Comment: ok, man and yeah I knew that, just forget it sometimes, but thanks alot man

Comment: ok, and it is, but it says in an error message though that the method must return a result of type double

Comment: @user3440080 You must have done something. Send me your new code in a new http://pastie.org

Comment: @user3440080 Oh you changed the method and I didn't notice. Here (just return it instead of printing it): http://pastie.org/8952343

Comment: ok man, yeah i changed it to printing it because for some reason when i did return it gave me an error, but ok ill try what u put now

Answer (score 2):

- Start with [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), this will return an array of `String`s
- Create an array of `double` set to the same size as the `String` array
- Iterate this array of `String`s and parse each value to a `double`, adding them to the `double` array
- Return this `double` array.
- Iterate the `double` array, adding each value to `sum` value of type `double`.
- Use [`Math.round`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) to round the result

Take a look at [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [Control Flow Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html), in particular [The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

*...Create an array of `double`...*

```
String[] ls = s.split(" ");
double[] doubles = new double[ls.length];
```

*...Iterate this array of `String`s and parse each value to a `double`...*

```
for (int index = 0; index < ls.length; index++) {
    doubles[index] = Double.parseDouble(ls[index]);
}
```

Comment: Why bother with the double array?  Why not just add them up as you parse them?

Comment: @DavidWallace Because the OP want to "return" them and then sum them... *"returns a double. Then using the doubles returned"*

Comment: @DavidWallace Personally, I'd do it your way to, saves messing around with multiple arrays, but that's what was asked for :P

Comment: @user3440080 Just as I said.  Take the "wordy" description and turn into code.  The question is more along the lines of, what part is giving your trouble...

Comment: well, hmm what was the way you were saying that you could avoid the array stuff? and the part that was giving me trouble was that once i did the "for" loop for making each of the numbers doubles, I didn't know how to then take the sum of those and return them to the nearest whole number

Comment: like after this double a = Double.parseDouble(ls[i]); i didnt know how to use "a" to compute the sum of them all

Comment: Basically, instead of creating a `double` array, for each value in the `String` array, simply parse it to double and add it to a `sum` variable directly, this forgoes the need for the `double` array entirly...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public double getSum(String dec)
{
   String[] nums = dec.split(" ");
   double total = 0;
   for(String a : nums)
       total += Double.parseDouble(a);
   return Math.round(total);
}
```

To read input just do

```
public void read()
{
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   //declare variable
   variableHere = scan.nextLine()  scan.nextInt() or w.e. you want
}
```

Comment: yeah something like that except how would i make it so that the string is an input from the user?

Comment: you use the Scanner class or an input stream linking it to System.in()

Comment: This solution is going to give rounding errors for certain inputs.

Comment: How so? I don't even round

Comment: `System.out.println(getSum("0.1 0.2"));` prints `0.30000000000000004`

Comment: @user2166592 He's talking about floating point number inaccuracy, so the `double`s

Comment: Nope, that won't help.  May I interest you in a `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @DavidWallace While what you are saying is 100% true, OP is going to round it anyway!

Comment: True i added in the Math.round so shouldn't really matter right?

Comment: Yes @ElliottFrisch, and OP may get into trouble if the fractional part of the answer is close to 0.5.

Comment: If it's like `12.500000004` it'll round up, but if it's `15.49999996` it'll round down. In rare cases, it will make a difference, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: The problem seems to be designed so that if you follow the instructions correctly, you automatically set yourself up to fall into problems with floating point errors.  I believe there's no good way to give a solution which always works correctly, and which follows the instructions.  I wonder whether the teacher intends this as a lead-in to teaching about floating point errors and the use of `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @DavidWallace You still have to discuss `MathContext` too, since `1/3` *requires* rounding.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Do I?  How do I write 1/3 on my input string of exact decimals?

Comment: @DavidWallace Fair enough, I'm still going to say the OP asked for a double... returning a BigDecimal wouldn't implement the required interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
public float rnd (String st) {

    String[] v = st.split(" ");
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for (String s : v) {
        sum += Float.valueOf(s);
    }
    return(Math.round(sum));
}
```

or replacing the `float` return by an `int` return (the question in not very clear on this).

Answer (score 0):

Here this works

```
package Split;

public class Split {

    public Split(){

        addEm("42.5 7.2 1.2");

    }//constructor 

    private void addEm(String st) {
        int i =0;
        int len = st.length();
        double sum =0 ;

        String s = "";
        st.charAt(0);
        for(int j =0; j< len;j++ ){
            s = s+st.charAt(j);
            if(st.charAt(j)==' ' || j==len-1){
                sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(s);
                s = "";

            } 
        }

        System.out.print(sum);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        new Split();
    }
}
```

the output will look like this

50.900000000000006...

Just round up the value to an int before output

Answer (score 0):

If I want to avoid all rounding problems, but don't care about using arrays or using doubles, I might do it like this.

```
public double splitAndSum(String input) {
    BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (String number : input.split("\\s+")) {
        sum = sum.add(new BigDecimal(number));
    }
    return sum.round(new MathContext(0)).doubleValue();
}
```